sfdmu command can't connect to sandbox
I am using sfdmu tool to migrate data between two sandboxes. While I have used sfdx force:auth:web:login and connected both orgs, I am always getting the below error when trying to run the sfdmu command:
[ERROR] Command initialization error: Attempt to connect to the yang.shi@anzx.com.test24 has been failed. Try to refresh the local sfdx CLI connection..

My connection of this sandbox seems to be pretty fine. When I do the sfdx org:display -u for this org, I got the following:
"status": 0,
  "result": {
    "id": "00DAD0000027Yjl2AE",
    "apiVersion": "61.0",
    "accessToken": "xxxxxxxxx",
    "instanceUrl": "https://anz--test24.sandbox.my.salesforce.com",
    "username": "yang.shi@anzx.com.test24",
    "clientId": "PlatformCLI",
    "connectedStatus": "Connected"
  },

Also, what I have tried:

Remove and re-install sfdmu.
Re-authorise this sandbox
Instead of using SSO, I have re-authed using username and password
Modify
.zshrc file to make it more accurate.

But none of the above worked for me. Any suggestions?

Did you try older version of sfdmu?

@Damecek No, how should I try that though

here is how, it should apply same way to sfdmu.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_install_plugin_version.htm

here is list of previous releases https://github.com/forcedotcom/SFDX-Data-Move-Utility/releases

so i would think of sf plugins install sfdmu@4.34.0
